# Can VS Code input text when I type a rapid shift shift sequence?

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir, keyboard-shortcuts

So, my new keyboard doesn't have the pipe key, and I use it frequently (I'm learning elixir right now). I know that `alt + 124` produces `|`, but it is a bit annoying to type it every time I want to use `|>` on elixir.

Is it possible to configure a shortcut (thought about something like shift shift) to insert `|>` in the editor?

Comment: Is it Windows, right?

Comment: yes, i'm on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has its own tool to create custom layouts.

[Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339).

Here is a brief how-to gracefully stolen from [MakeUseOf](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-custom-keyboard-layout-windows/)

- Open the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator app.
- Head to **File > Load Existing Keyboard**.
- Pick the layout you want to customize. You should make sure you pick the layout that matches your current keyboard setup, for example, **QWERTY (U.S.)**.
- Go to **File > Save Source File As** so you have a backup before you start making changes.
- Set your new keyboard’s parameters in **Project > Properties**. You can pick a language and give the keyboard a name and description.
- Click on a key and follow the on-screen prompt to remap it to a character of your choosing.

Assigning control keys combinations to input letters is not possible, AFAIK. Just set it so <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Something</kbd> *or* to any 3rd level key. BTW, I am pretty sure your current 3rd level *already* has a pipe, to test it press the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> (also called <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) and press all the alphanumeric keys.

Answer (score 1):

```json
{
  "key": "shift shift",
  "command": "type",
  "args": { 
    "text": "|>"
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Looks like using two modifier keys in rapid sequence will work soon.  Commit merged: see [Feature: Shift Shift, Ctrl Ctrl, Alt Alt Keybinds (Double press modifer keybind support)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/115190)

Will be in v1.54 - works in the Insiders Build now.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a keyboard shortcut

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+p",
  "command": "type",
  "args": { "text": "|>" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

You can choose any key combo you like, see the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)